# Creating link to hidden menus changes siteappearence in Joomla

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, content-management-system

I followed this tutorial to create some hidden aritcles with a hidden menue assigned to them http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_m ... _menu_item

If you go on this site http://fonag.org.ec/inicio/el-agua.html you will see a picture. Clicking on the paw in the picture (bottom left) is supposed to result so show a new picture, with the same appearence of the site. But clicking on the link, the site changes completly. The top images goes away as well as the menu on the left.

I assigned the same modules which are assigned to "El agua" to the hidden menue as you can see on this screenshot
http://s12.postimg.org/oydbyj7vh/module_Manager.png

In fact, both menus have the same modules assigned as you can see here

**Hidden Menu**
http://s12.postimg.org/9bm2l5u3h/hidden_Menu.png

**El Agua**
http://s12.postimg.org/lc7ilw1i5/el_Agua.png

Why is it not displaying? Working on Joomla 2.5 here.

Comment: Why aren't you creating the paw link using the menu item? I'm not sure that would solve the problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Also, Joomla 2.5 reaches end-of-life in a few weeks. You may want to do your upgrade before working much more.

Comment: @isherwood Coould you explain the "Why aren't you creating the paw link using the menu item?" Although, what means "end of life"? It still should work, shouldnt it?

Comment: @isherwood you mean like this? `href="/inicio/menu_title_alias`

Comment: No, I mean using your editor to select the menu item. That's the proper way to create a link in Joomla so it doesn't break if your alias changes.

Comment: End-of-life means that no security updates will be released, and extension developers will also discontinue support. Your site will be at greater risk of hacking and other failures as time goes on.

Comment: @isherwood since the link is in an imagemap, I have to toggle the editor to access the proper mapped part to insert the link. But when I toggle the editor, I cannot insert a link with i.e. JCE. Furthermore, I wont be able to select the menuitem cause its unplushed/hidden

Comment: You could create a link to the menu item anywhere and copy the url. Hidden menus are visible in JCE.

Comment: @isherwood nope. I dont see it. http://s12.postimg.org/7m7gwn959/screen.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
AS you can see in the screenshot the Menu Item is not published.
In order to work properly, it needs to be published.
Do not assign any moduls to the Menu (but to the menu item). That way, the menu stays hidden while with the assignment of the modules to the menuitem position and appereance can be controled.

Hope that will help someone in the future.